# Total Percentage Versus Each Percentage of same subject

Tags: percentages

I have 8 subjects in my course. Following are the data of attendance in each subject.

```
Subjects Attended/Total   Percentage
1         10/29            34.48 %
2.        23/23            100.00 %
3.        18/19            94.73 %
4.        18/19            94.73 %
5.        18/19            94.73 %
6.        18/19            94.73 %
7.        18/19            94.73 %
8.        18/19            94.73 %

------------------------------------
Total     141/166          87.85 %
```

But If I am calculating percentage only for `141/166 = 84.93 %`

There is a big difference => `87.85 - 84.93 = 2.92 %` for same attendances

So this difference is because of not rounding off correctly or my method is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. When you get $84.93\%$ you are considering each term with its weight (subjects have different totals):
$$WM=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^8 \%_i \times \text{total}_i }{\sum_{i=1}^8 \text{total}_i}, $$
while in $87.85 \%$ you're calculating
$$AM=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{i=1}^8 \%_i.$$
That's the difference between weighted arithmetic mean and arithmetic mean. The choice is up to you.

Comment: then which one is correct 84.93% or 87.85%

Comment: What do you want to calculate exactly?

Comment: Overall attendance %

Comment: I would use the weighted one, but they're both valid.